# Adding hydraulic gate closer to aluminum gate

Tags: gates

I have a small aluminum gate at my house which tends to slam shut. To address this, I thought of installing a Kant Slam closer. However, I’m facing a challenge with the installation, particularly with mounting the arm. The gate consists of small vertical aluminum posts, which don’t offer a suitable surface for mounting.

I’m considering creating a solid mounting surface, possibly using a combination of bolts and black metal plates, but I’m not entirely sure how to approach this. Does anyone have experience or suggestions on how to effectively add a mounting surface on such a gate for the Kant Slam closer? Any advice on materials, design, or installation techniques would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Pictures and measurements would help.

Comment: I’ve added two photos

Comment: Why not install it in alignment with a horizontal rail?